# TypeScript auto semicolon in WebStorm

Tags: typescript, webstorm, automatic-semicolon-insertion

I'm new at this world, and I'm trying to configure my WebStorm as similar as possible to Visual Studio Code, where I learned to code. WebStorm is the IDE in my new company and is totally new for me.

Any one knows how to add automatically semicolon `;` after each line when I save?

I tried looking through all the settings, but since this IDE is new for me I couldn't find something to help me!

Comment: related: [How can I setup webstorm to automatically add semi-colons to javascript functions, methods, etc](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11805103/how-can-i-setup-webstorm-to-automatically-add-semi-colons-to-javascript-function)

Comment: Possibly duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46641682/how-to-configure-eslint-auto-fix-on-save-in-webstorm-phpstorm

Comment: tl.dr On WebStorm 2020.1.1, there is a checkbox called Run eslint --fix on save

Comment: the IDE own formatter can also be configured to be run on Save, see https://www.jetbrains.com/help/webstorm/2022.3/saving-and-reverting-changes.html#actions-on-save